# convert dbf to csv without MS excel

Tags: python, csv, io, python-2.6, dbf

What is the best way (lowest computational cost) to convert a .dbf file into a .csv file without using `win32com.client` or other packages dependent on microsoft software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read dBase files using the [dbf package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf).  The package includes support for writing tables to CSV directly, or you could write your own with the The [Writer class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv#writer-objects) from the `csv` standard library module if you need more control.

Being pure Python it may not be the fastest solution available, but it should be portable.

Answer (score 1):

Lately I've been using the following code for quick and dirty csv to dbf conversions, primary in the context of preparing csv files for import into ArcGIS file geodatabases. The code uses the [dbf package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf).

```
import dbf, os
def csv_to_dbf(inCSV,outDBF):
    outFile = open(<temporary CSV>),'w')
    with open(inCSV,'r') as f:
        count = 0
        for line in f:
            if count == 0: header = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
            else: outFile.write(line)
            count +=1    
    dbf.from_csv(csvfile=<temporary CSV>, field_names=header, filename= outDBF ,to_disk=True)
    os.remove(<temporary CSV>)
```